# Не хочет работать ассемблерный код в VS2010

Tags: windows, ассемблер

Здравствуйте, делаю в студии ассемблерную вставку в майн с таким кодом

```
pushf
and dword ptr [esp],fffffffeh
popf
```

Почему во второй строке выдается ошибка? Существует ли книга типа ассемблер в VS2010?  Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте 0fffffffeh. На ассемблере если 16ричное число начинается с буквы, то перед ней нужно добавлять 0 (иначе оно может быть проинтерпретировано не как число, а как идентификатор).

Comment: Спасибо!!!! Заработало)))))

Answer (score 0):

ты хотя бы простой код попробуй, начни с создания месседжБокса, и тогда узнаешь работает студия или нет. Или запиши просто в память что-то.

mov ax, 2

дальше в олеДБ глянь записало или нет

Comment: Ха-ха-ха, пробовал, всё работает... и pushf работает... Когда раскоменчиваю and dword ptr [esp],fffffffeh работать перестает.
void main()
{
pushf
//and dword ptr [esp],fffffffeh; так работает
popf
}

Comment: А Вы 

    __asm {
        ...
    }

конечно пишите, просто здесь не прописали ? Кстати, сообщение об ошибке приведите полностью.

Comment: ой, писал, просто уже поздно и вылетело из головы написать на форуме....
error C2415: improper operand type  вот это вылетает..

Comment: Попробуйте pushf/popf заменить на pushfd/popfd. Вдруг компилятор настолько умный, что понимает: Вы кладете в стек 16 бит а AND делаете с 32-мя. На самом деле это будет верно. Или уберите DWORD и операнд замените на FFFEh.

Больше ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: Спасибо, но всё равно не работает ничего.... С этой студией прямо таки большая проблема...